# Standard Library Source File

Tags: c++, std

I am using GCC on cygwin, but I want to browse for source file of string.cpp from the standard library . I just want to read the source file for knowledge of the function I am using, but the problem is I can't find it anywhere. I only find the header files but not the source files. I assume it is store somewhere else, or maybe in another form? lib? dll? If so, then how can I extract that out..

Thx

Comment: The entire implementation is in the header file (it's a template class).

Comment: Yes, this question is nearly three years old, but please consider marking one of the responses as the correct answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`std::string` is actually a template specialization of [`std::basic_string`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.2/classstd_1_1basic__string.html) for the normal `char` type. Template C++ tends to end up solely in header files.

I haven't used the gcc library implementation, but there may well be no cpp files (or only files for implementing heavy lifting).

Answer (score 2):

On my installation, it's located in the vicinity of:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.3.4/include/c++/string
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.3.4/include/c++/bits/basic_string.h
```

to find this sort of stuff:

```
cd /usr
find . | grep string
```

Comment: Does cygwin support `locate`?  That's generally a better choice for large searches.

Comment: Also `bits/basic_string.tcc` for the function implementations.

Comment: With GNU grep a `grep -R ...` would have been enough (and this is Cygwin, after all).